# Alternative to TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification

Is there any alternative to `TfidfVectorizer` function of `sklearn.feature_extraction.text` module? I've heard of fastText and GloVe, but couldn't find a good expalnation of how to use it to vectorize text.

**Edit**: Basically I've a feature called narration, which consists of English sentences. In order to feed this into any ML algorithm I've to convert it into a numeric matrix representation. TfIdf was one way. Is there any other way that I can try out? (May or may not be under sklearn)

Comment: Is it correct that you want to count Term Frequencies (`TF`s) but you don't want to use `sklearn` for that and so you are looking for alternatives? This may be a bit broad topic for StackOverflow and I am not sure you'd get an answer. If by "vectorize" you mean embeddings than the examples you gave are with different purpose - word embeddings. In contrast the TfidfVectorizer simply counts the number of occurrences of each word in your document(s).

Comment: I've updated my description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called text embedding, see for example [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-network-embeddings-explained-4d028e6f0526). Essentially for your naration feature, you are looking to turn a sequence into vectors, hence seq_to_vec. TfIdf is just one of the simplest ways of doing this, which yields a sparse (many more components are =0, than not). I suggest you look [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/applied-text-analysis/9781491963036/ch04.html) for a good starting point.

Comment: The Spark NLP is a one place to look for it.